# how to divide each element of an entire list by a constant

Tags: python, list, function, set

I was trying to divide each elements of a list to see if the number in the list returns even number or not. What i want is to append the even values in `list_accepted_ant` to set_accepted_list. Currently, when i print the value, all the values are appended to `set_accepted_list`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
def DoIOpenTheDoor(list_ant_id):
    list_accepted_ant = []                      
    set_accepted_list = set()
    set_forbidden_list = set()
    set_list_ant_id = set(list_ant_id)
    if len(list_accepted_ant) < num_accepted:
        if len(list_ant_id) > 0:
            list_accepted_ant.extend(list_ant_id[0:min(len(list_ant_id))
                if (all(x % 2 == 0 for x in list_accepted_ant)): 
                    list_accepted_ant.append(list_accepted_ant)
    set_accepted_list = set(list_accepted_ant)  
    print "the set of even accepted ant-",(set_accepted_list) 
    print "the list of all ants-",(list_ant_id)    
    set_forbidden_list = set_list_ant_id-set_accepted_list
    return set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id,set_forbidden_list
```

This is my output when i run the code:

`list_ant_id = [1082, 1091, 1055, 1057, 971, 977, 728, 740]`

`set_accepted_list = set([1057, 1091, 740, 971, 977, 728, 1082, 1055])`

my expected `set_accepted_list = set([740,728,1082])`

Essentially what i want is to keep the even values from list_ant_id to the set_accepted_list.

Comment: you have an indentation error after `if len(list_ant_id) > 0:`

Comment: `list_accepted_ant ==0` is a boolean, and you are trying to do `for x in` that....a boolean, hence your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare an iterable `x/2 for x in list_accepted_ant` with a number `0`, so change:

```
([x/2 for x in list_accepted_ant ==0]): #for even number ants
```

to

```
all(x % 2 == 0 for x in list_accepted_ant))
```

the previous line is basically saying for every element of `list_accepted_ant` check that they all are even.

Comment: the error is solved, but i am not able to get the required result.

Comment: @imigyelvargasf. I have editted the question and provided the input and expected output.